# Save output of grep to file depending on grep match

Tags: regex, grep, cat

Got a quick question here:

Say I'm trying to separate the lines of a group of files, they all look like this:

pid text number

And I want to separate the lines into different files using the pid, how can I achieve this?

So far, I've tried something like:

```
cat files | grep '\([0-9]\{3\}\)' > $1.txt
```

That ofcourse, doens't work.. any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file with pids :

```
$ cat /tmp/l
123 azerty
234 qwerty
456 bepo
```

The awk code :

```
$ awk '/^[0-9]{3}/{print $0 > $1".txt"}' /tmp/l
```

The output of `ls` :

```
$ ls
123.txt
234.txt
456.txt
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm! Gotta start using awk more often :)